# How to redirect page if user not signed in using AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

So I'm planning on building a small site with a few pages hosted from a public S3 Bucket on AWS.  This site will have a public main page with links to login etc, and a couple of pages which are intended to be private - unless the user has signed in.

I have configured my Cognito user pools etc, and for now have been utilising the pre-built Cognito sign in/sing out forms.  I understand that when a user successfully signs in, either an access code or id_token can be provided back to the site URL upon redirect.

Is there a way in which I could/should utilise either the returned access code or id_token from the pre-built cognito forms to approve access to my 'private' pages on the site - potentially redirecting anyone who has not signed in back to the home page?